# Jest tests to check for inner function calls using spies

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to write some Jest tests to test if when a function call is made, its inner functions are also invoked. My functions look like this :

```js
fileCoordinator.js

export const save(var1, var2) {
  saveToFile(var1,var2)
  return var1 + var2
}

export saveToFile(var1, var2){
  console.log("saved")
}
```

My spec file looks like this:

```js
import * fileCoordinator from '../path'

it('should call the inner function', () => {
  let spy = jest.spyOn(fileCoordinator, "save")
  let spy1 = jest.spyOn(fileCoordinator, "saveToFile")
        
  fileCoordinator.save(1,2)
  
  expect(spy1).toHaveBeenCalled()

})
```

For some reason, this test fails because the function saveToFile was never called. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated, but why set a return value on spy1?

Comment: Not 100% sure. I've just been going off some stuff I found online that had the spy return value mocked. It shouldn't make a difference though for now at least

Comment: Right, but that function only has an implicit return (e.g., undefined).

Comment: True it could cause an issue later on so I'll get rid of it.

Comment: You can't mock a function that is defined and used in the same module. This is a fundamental property of JS, there's no way how this can work without patching the code. Separate them to different modules if you really need one of them mocked. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63336179/3731501

Answer (score 0):

These function definitions are not valid

```
export const save(var1, var2) {
  saveToFile(var1,var2)
  return var1 + var2
}
```

give a syntax error of `Missing initializer in const declaration`

Try

```
export const save = function(var1, var2) {
  saveToFile(var1,var2)
  return var1 + var2
}
```

or

```
export function save(var1, var2) {
  saveToFile(var1,var2)
  return var1 + var2
}
```